# how to change values for a selection field in odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo-10

How can I  update values for a selection field? I'm working on the module purchase article and I want to change the values of the type of article, for example, the article is Consumable, Service or stockable and I want it "beton", "nettoyage" or "d'entretien".

Comment: Please provide code on what you have done so far and explicitly mention where you're facing the problem.

Comment: Please ask Odoo related question in odoo forum for quick response: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1

Answer (score 2):

There are tow ways to add a value to an existing selection fields :

1. copy/paste the existing fields and add a vlue :

   ```
   _columns = {
   'type': fields.selection([('new_type', 'New type'),('consu', 'Consumable'),('service','Service')], 'Product Type', required=True, help="Consumable are product where you don't manage stock, a service is a non-material product provided by a company or an individual."),        
   }
   ```
2. using selection_add:

   ```
   type = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('new_type', 'New type')])
   ```